# Magento : CHAR_LENGTH in addFieldToFilter not working after 6788 patch

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a query where CHAR_LENGTH is used in addFieldToFilter like below

```
 $quotes_count =  Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()

    ->addFieldToFilter('part_quote_id', array("like" => $part_quote_id . "%"))
    ->addFieldToFilter('CHAR_LENGTH(part_quote_id)', '12')
    ->getSize();
```

I get the following error "Quote saving error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CHAR_LENGTH(part_quote_id)' in 'where clause'

This is after applying patch 6788. I know there is a fix for SQL injection, but couldn't find how to replace this

Answer (score 0):

Well.. i got the answer myself.

```
$quotes_count = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('part_quote_id', array("like" => $part_quote_id . "%"));
    // ->addFieldToFilter('CHAR_LENGTH(part_quote_id)', '12')
    // ->getSize();
$quotes_count->getSelect()->where("CHAR_LENGTH(part_quote_id) = 12");
$quotes_count = $quotes_count->getSize();
```

That did it for me!